# Node js Express Parallel Requests

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I develop an Nodejs app.I'm using ExpressJS.I've madesome routes to GET data from db.I want to get that data async. In other words i want that requests to be executed on parrallel. I've foundsome examples with callbacks but doesn't help me.Here is an example of request:

```
        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        app.get("/api",function(req,res){
        console.log("Test!");
          })
```

How should I write this to be executed async?I want to use node js module async.

Answer (score -1):

This is the example

```
   var app = require('express')();
   var path = require('path');

   var config = require('dotenv').config({
   path: path.join(__dirname + '/../../../.env')
   });


  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
  });
```

Comment: Example for what? Please add some describing words.

Comment: Follow these link to make you asyn connection                                                                                                                       (https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/) (https://www.terlici.com/2015/08/13/mysql-node-express.html)

Comment: You should write some words to your question.